# CodeIgniter form_dropdowns Database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, undefined

I dont know if my logic is incorrect but I cant get my form_dropdown  (down down list) list to populate with data from my database.

The error i get is Undefined property: stdClass::$name.

Code bellow.

My Array in $appertisers when print_r($appertisers);

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product] => Marinated mixed olives ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [product] => Simons ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [product] => Test ) )
```

**View**

```
            $array = array();
            foreach($appertisers as $row ){
                    $array = $row->name;
            }
            echo form_dropdown('appetisers',  $array);

    ?>
```

**Model**

```
    class Get_data extends CI_Model{
    function getAppertisers(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product FROM products WHERE cat = 1");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data = array();

    $this->load->model("get_data");
    $data['appertisers']  = $this->get_data->getAppertisers();

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('content_contact', $data);


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the row to the array, and reference the `product` property since there is no `name` property. You're currently just reassigning it:

```
foreach($appertisers as $row ){
    $array[] = $row->product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be:

```
class Get_data extends CI_Model
{
    function getAppertisers()
    {
        $this->db->where('cat', 1);
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row->product;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

your view:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('appertisers', '$appertisers', 'set_value('appetisers')'); ?>
```